# Makefile Wildcard Issues

Tags: linux, compilation, makefile, gnu

So I am having some issues understanding how exactly the % wildcard actually works using makefile. I have looked at static pattern rules in the GNU make man but i am still pretty confused and I feel like I have seen them do something similar to what I have below.

```
EXEC = a.out
CC = gcc
FLAGS = -Wall -c

$(EXEC): %.o
    $(CC) -o $(EXEC) $<
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $<

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
```

I keep getting an error that says %.o rule not defined. If someone could explain why this is wrong (probably in many ways, guessing the automatic variable part is incorrect as well) that would be appreciated !

Comment: `%` matches any part of the *target*  name - so it will match any part of `a.out`. Unless your source file file is called something like `a.out.c`, then it won't match anything at all. You might want to try using `*.o` instead (at your own risk of course).

Comment: also `$<` corresponds to the first dependency only. So if you have more than one source file (and hence more than one object file), only the first one will be compiled and linked into the executable. If using GNU make, you can use `$*` instead.

Comment: What object files do you want it to use to build `a.out`? If there are two source files, `a.c` and `b.c`, should it use both, or only `a.o`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you intend, but I'm pretty sure that this rule:

```
$(EXEC): %.o
    $(CC) -o $(EXEC) $<
```

doesn't do it. In this rule, '%' is not any kind of wildcard, it's just a character. So when Make tries build `a.out`, it goes looking for a file called `%.o`, can't find it, doesn't have a rule to build it (since there is no `%.c` and no way to build *that*), and gives up.

Your intention is unclear. If you want the rule to be able to build `a.out` from `a.o` (and likewise `foo.out` from `foo.o`, and `bar.out` from `bar.o`, and so on), write a [pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules):

```
%.out: %.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $<

$(EXEC): # Make will not use a pattern rule as the default, so we need this
```

(Note the use of [$@](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables).) Or (to restrict it to executables in the `EXEC` list) a [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
$(EXEC): %.out : %.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $<
```

If, on the other hand, you want Make to use *all the source files it can find* to build this executable, you must do something like this:

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.c) # make a list a.c foo.c bar.c
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SOURCES)) # translate it into a.o foo.o bar.o
$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $^ $<
```

Note the use of [the wildcard function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Function), and [$^](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) which expands to the list of prerequisites, and also note that "*.o" wouldn't do you much good.

Comment: When i tried your second example I get a "nothing to be done for all" could you tell me how exactly you got that to run?

Comment: @PandaRaid: there's no "all" target in your example or my answer. Do you have an "all" target in your makefile? Do you invoke Make by typing "make all"? And when you say my "second example", do you mean the pattern rule or the static pattern rule?

Comment: Sorry the pattern matching not static one. I wanted to do something along the lines of what is given in the 10.5.2 GNU example in pattern matching. Basically %.o: %.c but like you said it wont use pattern by default and I want it to be done for all the c files in a dir.

Comment: @PandaRaid: if you want to use all the c files in the dir, why not use my last example?

Comment: Yeah I tried it and it works, It is more of an experimentation thing for trying to understand exactly how to use the % wildcard. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

when I used to use makefiles long time ago they looked more like below. For each executable we listed the required object files explicitly.

```
CC = gcc
FLAGS = -Wall -c

prog1:    mod1.o mod2.o
    $(CC) mod1.o mod2.o -o prog1

prog2:    mod1.o mod3.o
    $(CC) mod1.o mod3.o -o prog2

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $<

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
```